# Laravel updating all records in many to many relationship

Tags: php, laravel

The tables `users` and `roles` are in many to many relationship through `role_user` as pivot table.
Below code statement finds a user by id and updates the first role successfully.

```
   User::findOrFail(1)->roles[0]->update(['name'=>'Admin']);
```

With below code I am intending to update all the user roles associated with the supplied user_id

```
User::findOrFail(1)->roles()->update(['name'=>'Admin']);
```

But I am getting following error

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'updated_at' in field list is ambiguous (SQL: update `roles` inner join `role_user` on `roles`.`id` = `role_user`.`role_id` set `name` = Admin, `updated_at` = 2018-02-06 09:06:30 where `role_user`.`user_id` = 1)
```

I understand `User::findOrFail(1)->roles` is a collection.

But the return value from `User::findOrFail(1)->roles()` is of type `BelongsToMany`

is this an object ?  and why cannot we use `update()` method on it ?

Comment: so you want same role in multiple row for a single user??

Comment: @Sohel0415 my bad, why would I want that, got it now , thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it's many-to-many relationship, you need to use [`sync()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships) method if you want to set only one role for specified user:

```
$user = User::find(1);
$roleId = Role::where('name', 'Admin')->value('id');
$user->roles()->sync([$roleId]);
```